# Easier way of writing code

Tags: google-sheets

I have a lot of this one line to write that changes for each cell. I was wondering if there was a faster way of writing it (considering it requires 10 AND statements for 5 different cells)

```
=NOT(OR(AND(H16 = "Yes", H12 = "Yes"), AND(H16 = "Yes", H13 = "Yes"), 
AND(H16 = "Yes", H14 = "Yes"), AND(H16 = "Yes", H15 = "Yes"), 
AND(H15 = "Yes", H12 = "Yes"), AND(H15 = "Yes", H13 = "Yes"), 
AND(H15="Yes", H14="Yes"), AND(H14="Yes", H12="Yes"), AND(H14="Yes", H13="Yes"), 
AND(H13="Yes", H12="Yes")))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in simple terms what you are trying to achieve? Is it OK if one cell is yes, but not if more than one is yes?

Comment: Well, now I need something like this, except, instead of "not (at least 2 Hxx contain Yes)", it's not( at least 1 HXX contain Yes)"

Comment: "at least one is true" is simply `OR(c16,c15,c14,c13)`. Put it inside a not().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition seems to be

```
not(or( and(c16, or( c15,c14,c13,c12)),
        and(c15, or(     c14,c13,c12)),
        and(c14, or(         c13,c12)),
        and(c13,                 c12 )
   )
```

where *c16* stands for `H16="Yes"`, etc.

and it means "not (at least 2 Hxx contain Yes)", that is "at most one Hxx contains Yes".